# Exception: Partition key provided ..., when using CreateDocumentUri with a partitioned document db

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

`DeleteDocumentAsync` and `ReadDocumentAsync` don't work for me when I have a partitioned collection. I used the `RequestOptions`:

```
await client.DeleteDocumentAsync(document.SelfLink, new RequestOptions { 
    PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("mykey")
}).ConfigureAwait(false); // This works.

var uri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri("db", "coll", "id1");

await client.DeleteDocumentAsync(uri, new RequestOptions { 
    PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("mykey")
}).ConfigureAwait(false); // This throws
```

> Partition key provided either doesn't correspond to definition in the collection or doesn't match partition key field values specified in the document.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is `myKey` in `new PartitionKey("mykey")` the name of the PartitionKey attribute (e.g. `lastName`) or the value of the attribute (e.g. `Smith`)?

Comment: Thanks for the help, but why will it succeed with the SelfLink with the wrong value?

Comment: @Jose I can't delete documents with selfLink or uri if i set the wrong value the partition key.Would you please post your sample data structure?  BTW, the class should be the RequestOptions not RequestOption in your code.

Comment: @Jose Hi,any progress?Does my answer helps you?

Comment: Sorry @Jay, I've been busy somewhere else. I'll try soon to rewrite a simple sample outside our code-base, which was written by somebody else.

Comment: @Jose Sure,waiting for your response.

Comment: Yes. You are both right. I found the issue in my code using the wrong collection name. Thanks to all.

Comment: How have you created the DocumentCollection (which which settings)? The collection already expects a proper definition of the partition key on creation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried the your snippet of code which throws exception, it works for me.

I think you misunderstand the meaning of `partitionkey` property in the `RequestOptions`.

For example , my container is created like this:

[image]

The partition key is "name" for my collection here. You could check your collection's partition key.

And my documents as below :

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "jay"
}

{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "jay2"
}
```

My `partitionkey` is **'name'**, so here I have two paritions : **'jay'** and **'jay1'**.

So, here you should set the `partitionkey` property to 'jay' or 'jay2',not 'name'.

```
var uri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri("db", "part", "1");

client.DeleteDocumentAsync(uri, new RequestOptions
{
    PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("jay")
}).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I can't see the definition of the partition key in the screenshot where you created the container. Could you explain that part please? Because here I am having difficulties - I know how to pass the key later in CRUD operations, but seem to have something wrong on creation of the collection. How do you specify which is the partition key?